# find and kill process in ksh script (linux) not working

Tags: ksh, kill

I have been trying to find and kill any stale process left after the stop in a ksh script on a linux machine and it doesnt seem to work. It works from the command line but in the script though

here is the code

```
echo "kill any process still running"
ps -ef | grep qpasa |grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill
```

and here is the output from the script log

```
usage: kill [ -s signal | -p ] [ -a ] pid ...
       kill -l [ signal ]
```

can you you please let me know what am I doing wrong here

Comment: what is the output for the same command without the last "kill command" ?
" ps -ef | grep qpasa |grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' "

Answer (score 1):

I think you call the script when no processes are running. Try `kill` without arguments and you get the same message.
You can redirect the error to `/dev/null` but I would try something else:

```
ps -ef | grep qpasa |grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | while read pid; do
   echo "Killing ${pid}"
   kill ${pid}
   sleep 2
   kill -9 ${pid} 2>/dev/null
done
```

The first `kill` gives `qpasa` the possibility to the stop controlled: Flush caches and close handles. Give qpasa 2 seconds for it.
When `qpasa` ignores the signal, `kill` it the hard way. Of course the process could have stopped already, so this time we want to ignore error messages.

When you have a lot of qpasa processes, you want to sleep 2 seconds only once.
First loop through all processes with a friendly kill, wait 5 seconds, and than hard kill the processes you find. When you make a function `kill_qpasa_signal` for the looping (and using $1 as kill signal), you can use

```
kill_qpasa_signal 15
sleep 5
kill_qpasa_signal 9
```